# Webpack - Import Less from TypeScript fails (css-loader)

Tags: css, typescript, webpack, css-loader, extract-text-plugin

I'm trying to build a test project with TypeScript via Webpack. Have just **index.ts** file and **base.less** (or base.css) file imported in **index.ts** and it fails with errors on **css-loader**. Without imported LESS (CSS) file in a .ts file all working good.

I have got another big project with JS only (no TypeScript) and it working good with the same webpack.config file (babel instead of ts loader).

Webpack@2.2.0

All needed loaders are installed.

[webpack.config.js](https://bitbucket.org/vashchukmaksim/m18test/src/e0787dcf9b1729f9f142facea8a37e874f04fec5/webpack.config.js?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) and [Bitbucket link to the test project](https://bitbucket.org/vashchukmaksim/m18test/src/e0787dcf9b1729f9f142facea8a37e874f04fec5?at=master)

> ERROR in ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js
>       Module build failed: Error: Final loader didn't return a Buffer or String

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wrong `RegExp` rule for TypeScript loader in your `webpack.config.js`. You need this:

```
`test: /(.ts|.tsx)$/`
```

but you have this:

```
`test: /(.ts|.tsx)?/`
```

Which says: load as TypeScript file no matter what.

Comment: I fixed it today but have not push yet. But ts scripts work fine. Webpack gives an error only when I write "import './less/base.less'. I found (in webpack2 documentation) that I need to add .d.ts file with declare '*.less' (and CSS) but still it did not help, got the same error. Just 10 minutes and I will push my updated files. Now there is a JS file with imported less that works and TS file with only TS code without importing styles that also works. But if I move import from styles.js to index.ts I got an error above.

Comment: webpack gives an error on `import 'base.less'` because it thinks that it is a `.ts` file. Fix the RegExp rule as I suggested and everything will be OK

Comment: Yes! It works... Unbelievable. I fix ? with $ but got another error in this Regexp. Thanks!!!